# How can I use perl/awk/sed to search for all occurrences of text wrapped in quotes within a file and then delete them?

Tags: regex, perl, shell, sed, ksh

How can I use perl, awk, or sed to search for all occurrences of text wrapped in quotes within a file, and print the result of deleting those occurrences from the file? I do not want to actually alter the file, but simply print the result of altering the file like sed does.

For example, say the file contains the following :

```
data|more data|"not important"|"more unimportant stuff"
```

I need it to print out:

```
data|more data||
```

But I want to leave the file intact. I tried using sed but I could not get it to accept regexs.

I have tried something like this:

```
sed -e 's/\<["]+[^"]*["]+\>//g' file.txt
```

but it does nothing and prints the original file.
Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a few extra characters in your `sed` command.

```
sed -e 's/"[^"]*"//g' file.txt
```

Input:

```
"quoted text is here" but not quoted there
never more
"hello world" foo bar
data|more data|"not important"|"more unimportant stuff"
```

Output:

```
 but not quoted there
never more
 foo bar
data|more data||
```

Comment: As Pierre said in his answer, you don't need so many brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/".*?"//g' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'data|more data|"not important"|"more unimportant stuff"' | sed -E 's/"[^"]*"//g'
```

You don't need to declare a character class (brackets) for only one character...

Comment: I do however want it to delete strings in double or triple quotes as well.. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Then it's not the way to do it. Consider the following example : "I'll go to school tomorrow"... you're gonna delete "I' and start deleting stuff again from the next "

Comment: I can guarantee there are no single quotes in the file. There are just multiple occurrences of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $cnt=qq(data|more data|"not important"|"more unimportant stuff");
my @arr = $cnt =~ m{(?:^|\|)([^"][^\|]*[^"])(?=\||$)}ig;
print "@arr";
```

This code might help you..

Comment: It could be nice to explain your solution. Specifying which language you use is also important for readers.